# Css hover child to trigger effect on parent

Tags: html, css, hover, parent-child

I have this HTML code:

```
<span id="search">
 <input type="submit" value="" id="button">
</span>
```

I want to change the opacity of `#search::after` when hovering `#button`

```css
#button:hover #search::after {opacity:1;}
```

It wont work so I wonder if its even possible to do this.

Comment: Thats some really bad news...

Comment: In this case if you want to show the after element and there is no other elements just the input ... isn't the same trigger the hover on the parent span?

Answer (score 4):

Using only CSS It's impossible.

What you can do is to use JavaScript/Jquery to trigger a action, like this:

```
$("#button").hover( function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
});
```

and in your css:

```
#search.hover::after {opacity:1;}
```

Related: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?rq=1)

Comment: OP wants CSS only Solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with just CSS. You might try using Javascript to help with this.

```
$("#button").on("mouseenter",function(e){
     $("#search:after").css({"opacity":1});
})
```

However, in order to make a selection with a pseudo class, you'll need the jQuery psuedo shim:

http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/pseudo/jquery.pseudo.js

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer but its a pity you cant do this with CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible because CSS doesn't have a parent selector.

But if you can change your html markup, then you can use [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) selector `+`

```css
#button:hover + #search::after {
  content: "hovered"
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="hover me" id="button" />
<span id="search"></span>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of your search container? Does it match the child? If so adding the hover to search will achieve the same effect. Otherwise you'll need to rearrange your markup or use javascript. I'm all for simple solutions though.

Comment: No, the container is way bigger: 135x35. The child covers only the right corner.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Use Selector** "*+*"

> HTML

```
<a id="tooldrop">HOVER ME !</a>
<ul id="dropea">
  <li>ONE</li>
  <li>TWO</li>
</ul
```

> CSS

```
    ul#dropea li{
        background-color: red;padding: 10px;opacity: 0;transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    #tooldrop:hover + ul#dropea li {
      transform: rotate(0) scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

===========================================

*JUST ADD "+" EVERY NEW ELEMENT*

> HTML

```
<a id="tooldrop">HOVER ME !</a>
<div class="block"></div>
<ul id="dropea">
  <li>ONE</li>
  <li>TWO</li>
</ul>
```

> CSS

```
   ul#dropea li{
     background-color: red;padding: 10px;opacity: 0;transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    #tooldrop:hover + div.block + ul#dropea li {
      transform: rotate(0) scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

---

ExteraDex[image]